# issue with WHERE clause using .Net Connector for SAP

Tags: c#, sql, abap, sap-dotnet-connector

Trying to read a table and this is my WHERE clause.

```
"((DISPO EQ 'E10' OR DISPO EQ 'EAA') AND (GLTRP >= '20150701' AND GLTRP <= '20150730'))"
```

I have also tried

```
"(DISPO EQ 'E10' OR DISPO EQ 'EAA') AND (GLTRP >= '20150701' AND GLTRP <= '20150730')"
```

and

```
"(DISPO EQ 'E10' OR DISPO EQ 'EAA') AND GLTRP >= '20150701' AND GLTRP <= '20150730'"
```

I have messed with using =, EQ, >=, GL etc etc and I keep getting the same error

```
An exception of type 'SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcAbapRuntimeException' occurred in sapnco.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A comparison value is missing from the dynamic WHERE condition.
```

now if I split the WHERE clause and try things separately then everything works fine.

```
DISPO EQ 'E10' OR DISPO EQ 'EAA' // This works
```

and

```
GLTRP >= '20150701' AND GLTRP <= '20150730' // This also works.
```

for good measure, this also works

```
GLTRP BETWEEN '20150701' AND '20150730'
```

So what is wrong with my original WHERE clause?

UPDATE: How the code is executed.

```
IRfcFunction BapiGetOrderStatus = SapRap.CreateFunction("BBP_RFC_READ_TABLE");

BapiGetOrder.SetValue("QUERY_TABLE", "AFKO")

BapiGetOrder.SetValue("DELIMITER", ";");

BapiGetOrder.SetValue("ROWCOUNT", "30");

// Parameter table FIELDS contains the columns
IRfcTable fields = BapiGetOrders.GetTable("FIELDS");
fields.Append();
fields.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "AUFNR");
fields.Append();
fields.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "GLTRP");
fields.Append();
fields.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "GSTRP");
fields.Append();
fields.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "GAMNG");
felds.Append();
fields.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "STLBEZ");
fields.Append();
fields.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "DISPO");
fields.Append();
fields.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "APRIO");
fields.Append();
fields.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "IGMNG");
fields.Append();
fields.SetValue("FIELDNAME", "IASMG");

IRfcTable optsTable = BapiGetOrder.GetTable("OPTIONS");
optsTable.Append();

optsTable.SetValue("TEXT", " ( ( DISPO EQ 'E10' OR DISPO EQ 'EAA' ) AND ( GLTRP >= '20150701' AND GLTRP <= '20150730' ) ) ");

BapiGetOrders.Invoke(SapRfcDestination); // <------- EXCEPTION HERE

IRfcTable ItemsTable = BapiGetOrders.GetTable("DATA");
```

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need spaces on the inside of the parentheses:

```
"( ( DISPO EQ 'E10' OR DISPO EQ 'EAA' ) AND ( GLTRP >= '20150701' AND GLTRP <= '20150730' ) )"
  ^ ^                                ^       ^                                           ^ ^
```

Comment: Tried what you said and now I get `Additional information: A relational operator is missing in the dynamic WHERE condition.`

Comment: In this case it might be handy, to catch the nco-exception  with the entire stacktrace and log the stacktrace. How does Your entire statement look like, how is it created and how is it passed ?

Answer (score 1):

Your last comment indicate that the message contins a reference to dynamic condition. Dynamic WHERE condition are in the form

```
... WHERE (variable).
```

with variable being a string containing the condition.

Since you do not have such a dynamic condition, I think, as vwegert, that ou got a problem with space in your condition. Your second solution should work if you add space before and after each ) and (.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a linebreak into your SQL, I think your SQL was trimmed every perform it. Maybe because it is too long.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is too long. Any WHERE text exceeding 70 characters will not execute properly. Break up your where clause and append two records to the table.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.